# What is the alternative to swift’s DispatchGroup in flutter/dart?

Tags: swift, dart, flutter

I would like to know how I can write this code in flutter/dart? I don't know any Class in the flutter that can notify certain code to execute after another code completes.

```
var posts = [Post]()

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        snapshot.forEach({ (postSnapshot) in
            guard let postDict = postSnapshot.value as? [String : Any],
                let posterUID = postDict["poster_uid"] as? String
                else { return }

            let postKey = postSnapshot.key

            dispatchGroup.enter()

            showUserPost(forKey: postKey, posterUID: posterUID) { (post) in
                if let post = post {
                    posts.append(post)
                }

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        })

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            completion(nil, posts.reversed())
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple alternatives :

`Listenable` such as `ValueNotifier`, provided by flutter

```
  final  valueNotifier = new ValueNotifier(42);
  valueNotifier.addListener(() {
    print(valueNotifier.value);
  });
  valueNotifier.value++; // automatically notify all listener
```

Or `Stream`/`Sink` and it's `StreamController` which is coming from `dart:async`.

```
final streamController = new StreamController<int>.broadcast();
streamController.stream.listen((value) {
  print(value);
});
streamController.sink.add(45);
```

Prefer `Stream` over `Listenable` when you can. As dart natively support streams and make it's usage easier with some syntax sugar such as :

```
await for (final value in stream) {
  print(value);
}
```

or

```
Stream<int> createStream() async* {
  yield 42;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. ValueNotifier is just what I was looking for I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think alternatively you can also utilize `Future.wait`

[image]

credit to [easy FLUTTER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUSmY5ZbgL4) for the picture